# How do i add values together in a user defined object list dart?

Tags: dart

```
List<Product> myProducts = [];
```

I have made a list builder so that with every product clicked it is added to the list

```
myProducts.add(Product(
   id: product.id,
   name: product.name,
   price: product.price
));
```

how do I add the price of all the values in the list?

I wasn't sure what to do so I tried researching

`myProducts.reduce((value, element) => element.price + value.price)`

is this the way to do it?
I hope to get the sum of all the values in my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double totalPrice = myProducts.fold(0, (sum, product) => sum + product.price);
```